# notifications issue in ios 6 ,5 ans 4

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications

iam getting some date and time like appointment time. i want to remind the user before to that particular time.i googled and got some knowledge but still in small confusion where to write my code shall i in application entered back ground method and i have to use alert views or any other .please help me.

```
     NSString *today=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",appDelegate.appointmentDate,appDelegate.timeStart1];
    NSLog(@"%@",today);


    NSDateFormatter *format=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

    [format setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"];
    NSDate *date1=[format dateFromString:today];
           NSLog(@"%@",date1);


    NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *datefo1 =[[NSDateComponents alloc]init];
    [datefo1 setMinute:1];

  [datefo1 setSecond:0];

    NSDate *alerttime=[cal dateByAddingComponents:datefo1 toDate:date options:0];

    UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    UILocalNotification* notifyAlarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc]
                                        init];
    if (notifyAlarm)
    {
        notifyAlarm.fireDate = alerttime;
        notifyAlarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        notifyAlarm.repeatInterval = 0;

        notifyAlarm.alertBody = @"you have an appointment  in 30 minutes";
        [app scheduleLocalNotification:notifyAlarm];
    }
```

i want notification like on top i want to display some alert even my app is running and not running also. but its coming with out any message, where i am going wrong shall i need to use nsnotification center are some thing else. sorry for my poor english.thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You're using local notifications, which is a good start, but you should know that local notifications are only displayed if your app is in the background. If your app is running in the foreground when the time comes you will need to display the notification yourself (UIView / UIAlertView).

You can schedule the local notification whenever you want, it really depends what editing you allow the user to do and, therefore, how much you might need to cancel the local notification and schedule a new version.

Few other things:

- Consider using 'NSDate -dateByAddingTimeInterval' (it's just less code for your use case)
- You're adding a minute to your date, so the alarm will be after the event (and say the appointment is in 30 minutes time ?)
- Use NSLocalizedString for any string that will be displayed to the user
- In the future, store less data in the appDelegate, that ins't what that class is for :)

Comment: thanks for reply i have some doubt if suppose my app is not in foreground then

Comment: when app is running is there any way like defaultly it should show on top of icon

Comment: If your app is not in the foreground, then the local notification will be displayed at the fire date. Are you not seeing it? Consider adding a couple of logs to check the fire date and that the local notification is truly created.

Comment: If the app is running (i.e. in the foreground), then you can't see the icon, so I don't follow your question.

Comment: if i use application did entered back ground method with same code its showing on top of of screen like the same way if app is running also. shall i need to use push notifications